# Variadic generic lambda and function overload

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following variadic generic lambda and overloaded `foo()` function defined.

```
template <typename Lambda>
auto bar(Lambda&& lambda) {
    return [lambda = std::forward<Lambda>(lambda)](auto&& ...args) {
        return lambda(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

void foo(std::function<void()>&& cmd, std::function<void()>&& callback) { std::cout << "void" << std::endl; }
void foo(std::function<bool()>&& cmd, std::function<bool()>&& callback) { std::cout << "bool" << std::endl; }
```

The following 3 `foo()` calls print "void".

```
int main()
{
    // 1
    foo(
        bar( []() {} ),
        bar( []() {} )
    );
    // 2
    foo(
        bar( []() { return true; } ),
        bar( []() {} )
    );
    // 3
    foo(
        bar( []() {} ),
        bar( []() { return true;} )
    );
    // 4) compiler error: foo is ambiguous
    // foo(
    //     bar( []() { return false; } ),
    //     bar( []() { return true; } )
    // );
}
```

Could you please help me to understand why it successfully compiles statements 1-3 but fails to compile statement 4?

gcc 7.5.0

Comment: I'm curious if `bar` has any purpose. Doesn't seem to make any difference for this example. I guess it would force any functor to have a placeholder return type, but I can't think of what that might do different.

Comment: Right, but it was not clear to me when asked the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::function<void()>` can store a function with any return type (`void` or not), its return value is discarded.

Because of that, in (4) both overloads are applicable, and the compiler can't decide which one to use.

In (1), (2), and (3) on the other hand, at least one of the two lambdas returns `void`, so the `bool` overload of `foo` is not applicable.

---

Possible solutions are:

- When passing a functor into `foo`, cast it to a proper specialization of `std::function` first. (doesn't look too good)
- Write a custom wrapper/replacement for `std::function`, with a different SFINAE for the constructor. (takes effort)
- Make `foo` a template (use template parameters as types for the callbacks). Then use `decltype` to determine the return type, and act accordingly. (this is what I would do)